Cost-Effective Method for Daily Aggregation of Access Logs on Google Cloud
I'm working on aggregating load balancer access logs in Google Cloud to build a dataset that tracks daily metrics. Specifically, I need to record the number of requests per endpoint and the unique IPs that visit these endpoints each day.
While Google Cloud's Log Analytics tool provides access to this data, it seems to lack API support, which prevents automating these queries for daily aggregation. This is crucial for cost-effectiveness, as storing a large volume of access logs directly is expensive.
Does anyone know of a cost-effective solution or alternative approach to automate the daily aggregation of these metrics without incurring high storage costs?

You can create a linked dataset in BigQuery and then use it to query your data (with your aggregation) every day. Typically, with a scheduled query in BigQuery.
However, you need to store first your logs in Cloud Logging to make it query-able in BigQuery.
Of course, you can use a custom logging bucket with a retention of a few days to limit the storage size, but the log processing and storage in this bucket will be billed (and it's the most expensive part)

Before your answer i set up a log router sink to a bigquery dataset, with a expiration of 2 days for the tables. Is that what you meant or are you refferring to another procedure?

yes. In my case, you are not sinking the logs in a bigquery table. The logs stay in the Logging Bucket (maybe a custom one with a shorter retention) and you can create a linked dataset with Log Analytics: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/buckets#link-bq-dataset
